# The general solution of $f''+2ff'=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If
$$f''+2ff'=0,$$
let $g(f)=f'$. Then
$$g(f)\frac{dg(f)}{df}+2fg(f)=0,$$
so
$$g(f)\left(2f+\frac{dg(f)}{df}\right)=0$$
which is true iff
$$g(f)=0\text{ or } 2f+\frac{dg(f)}{df}=0.$$
In the first case,
$$f(x)=\int 0\, dx=c_1;$$
in the second case,
$$g(f)=\int -2f\, df=-f^2+c_2,$$
so
$$\int \frac{df/dx}{-f^2+c_2}\, dx=\int dx$$
which means
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{c_2}}\right)=x+c_3.$$
Then we get
$$f(x)=\sqrt{c_2}\tanh ((x+c_3)\sqrt{c_2}).$$
But
$$\frac{1}{x-1}$$
is also a solution of
$$f''+2ff'=0,$$
yet it is not of the form $\sqrt{c_2}\tanh ((x+c_3)\sqrt{c_2})$ or of the form $c_1$. How is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand how you converted $f''$ into $g(f)\frac{dg(f)}{df}$.

Comment: @PavelKocourek Just use the chain rule

Comment: @PavelKocourek $g(f)\frac{dg(f)}{df}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg(f)}{df}=\frac{dg(f)}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}f'=f''$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your work, when you get to the equation
$$\int \frac{df/dx}{-f^2+c_2}\, dx=\int dx$$
you should distinguish three cases: $c_2>0$ (done), $c_2=0$ and $c_2<0$.

When $c_2=0$, we have that
$$\int \frac{df/dx}{-f^2}\, dx=\int dx\implies  \frac{1}{f}=x+c_3\implies f(x)=\frac{1}{x+c_3}.$$
Can you handle the case $c_2<0$? Something involving $\arctan$ will turn out...